# trouble with accelerate and decelerate methods

Tags: java, methods

I need some help implementing a accelerate and decelerate methods for an asteroids clone I am working on.

```
public void accelerate(){
    //i am if an object is traveling at 10 this makes it travel slower
            if(getSpeed()>10){
        xVelocity-=.1*Math.sin(angle);
        yVelocity-=.1*Math.cos(angle);
    }           
    this.xVelocity+=.1*Math.sin(angle);
    this.yVelocity+=.1*Math.cos(angle);
}   
public void deccelerate(){

    this.xVelocity-=.1*Math.sin(angle);
    this.yVelocity-=.1*Math.cos(angle);
    if(getSpeed()<0){
        return;
    }

}
```

I want to have the accelerate run when the up key is pressed and deccelerate when it is not pressed. My problem is that the ship just travels backwards when I run the game.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the maths I run in the methods or a better way to implement this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `deccelerate()` decreases the speed even if the deccelerateis already very slow and close to 0.

You shoud not decrease the speed before checking the speed will not be under 0. If you decrease it and then do the check (and return), then if the spead is under 0, even if you return, the speed remains under 0... But you already set it under 0..... so it seems normal it's going backward